# Counting number in one column with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a simple excel sheet with number starting from 1 - 50 in column "I"

To count many cell with value in column "I", I use this formula

```
=COUNT("I:I")
```

How can I use the similar method in VBA?

Currently Istruggle to finish the code below:

```
number = WorksheetFunction.Count(Range("I:I"))
```

I need advise to modified the code to become more independent by current cell selected (for example I will place the cell in column "H" and then run the VBA. the code automatically select range of column next to the cell and count cell that have value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use OFFSET:

```
number = application.WorksheetFunction.Count(selection.offset(,1).entirecolumn)
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. It exactly solve what i looking for ! :)